# Do an action automatically every n minutes with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I want, for example, to move the context.object every 10 minutes automatically.
So no action needed, if I run my script the first time it will activate this incremental action, and if I run it a second time it will stop listening.

Is it even possible to do those kind of loop actions ?

I know we can get time information with

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.now()
date= time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d_%HH%MM%S")
```

---

Thanks to RUben for this answer, so i had another problem, once i launch a timer, impossible to stop it with another run of any code.

this for example

```
def every_1_seconds_word():
    print("World")
    return 1.0

bpy.app.timers.register(every_1_seconds_word)
```

but i can break the timer if it respect a condition

```
def every_1_seconds_word():
    print("World")
    if it.respect.the.condition.im.writing.right.now == n:
        return None
    return 1.0

bpy.app.timers.register(every_1_seconds_word)
```

but i don't know yet how to do this because i need to create a new condition line within blender itself, it need to be accessible on every run of the code, wso why not using an existing one ? for example with:

```
def every_1_seconds_word():
    print("World")
    if bpy.context.scene.cycles.preview_start_resolution == 9999:
        return None
    return 1.0

bpy.app.timers.register(every_1_seconds_word)
```

by using the start resolution parameters for example, i can create another code that can play on this to break my timer.

```
A = bpy.context.scene.cycles.preview_start_resolution
bpy.context.scene.cycles.preview_start_resolution = 9999

def in_1_seconds():
    bpy.context.scene.cycles.preview_start_resolution = A
bpy.app.timers.register(in_1_seconds, first_interval=1)
```

this is quite a macgyver solution but well it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Application Timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.timers.html) documentation for Blender **2.80** it quite simple:

```
def in_1_seconds(obj):
    if obj.location.y > 0.5:
        return None
    else:
        obj.location += Vector((0.0, 0.1, 0.0))
        return 1

bpy.app.timers.register(functools.partial(in_1_seconds, bpy.context.active_object))
```

functools used to anchor active object to timer

timer function returns a float with seconds to next delay which may be changed dynamically

return None to stop function execution in test purpose it can be Keyboard Interrupted

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation ! how do we unregister a perpetual timer once it is register ?

Comment: existing API implementation Timer cannot be cleared apart from itself