# Unregister Timers with parameters

Tags: python

I am trying to use a timer for a function, but I need to provide it a parameter so I'm using the example from https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.timers.html:

```
import bpy
import functools

def print_message(message):
    print("Message:", message)

bpy.app.timers.register(functools.partial(print_message, "Hello"), first_interval=2.0)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to unregister it.
Trying with this:

```
if bpy.app.timers.is_registered(functools.partial(print_message, "World"):
    bpy.app.timers.unregister(functools.partial(print_message, "World")
```

Or this:

```
if bpy.app.timers.is_registered(print_message):
    bpy.app.timers.unregister(print_message)
```

Or even this:

```
   if bpy.app.timers.is_registered(functools):
        bpy.app.timers.unregister(functools)
```

And a lot of other things, but that doesn't work. Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: bpy.app.timers has not unregister function, but timer function can return False to stop execution, [try look at this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141064/do-an-action-automatically-every-n-minutes-with-python/141065#141065)

Comment: I have been able to unregister timers, it actually unregisters if I don't check if it's registered first (it does throw an error though, maybe it's trying to unregister itself twice). 
But the return None solution works great, so thanks for your help!

Comment: @RUben `bpy.app.timers` has an `unregister` function listed [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.timers.html#bpy.app.timers.unregister)

Comment: It's a bit weird that bpy.app.timers.is_registered doesn't work when using parameters. It must be expecting a specific argument that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in Python, but if my knowledge from JavaScript translates well enough, then this is caused by the fact that the created function references are not equal. Let's say, you have a function called `a`:

```
def a(x, y):
    return x + y
```

It is stored as a reference, that can be assigned to multiple variables that will be equal to each other and itself as well:

```
print(a == a) # True
b = a
print(a == b) # True
```

But each time you call `functools.partial`, it creates a new function reference, which are then not equal to each other, not even if their parameters are the same:

```
c = functools.partial(a, 5)
d = functools.partial(a, 5)
print(c == d) # False
```

Or alternatively you can even directly compare the results.

```
print(functools.partial(a, 5) == functools.partial(a, 5)) # False
```

Because of this, if you want to later unregister a function created with `functools.partial`, you need to store a reference to it, so Python will be able to find which one to unregister by checking for equality among the registered ones, like for example this way:

```
e = functools.partial(print_message, "World")
bpy.app.timers.register(e, first_interval=2.0)
```

after which you can use the following code to unregister:

```
if bpy.app.timers.is_registered(e):
    bpy.app.timers.unregister(e)
```

because

```
print(e == e) # True
```