# Is there a way to infinitely make a certain mesh appear in blender?

Tags: mesh

Is there a way to infinitely make a certain mesh appear in blender?

I am animating a production line. I want a mesh to appear at a certain place every 10 seconds, so the longer we run the animation, the more mesh there is in memory.

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/141065/86891

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Animation Nodes](https://animation-nodes.com/) to do that without coding.

[image]

Create a source collection to pick the object templates from.

[image]

Then:

- Test if time is reached using a *"repeat time"* node. *"Repeat time"* will loop from 0 to a given value over time.
- Get a random object from the source collection.
- Create an instance when time is reached and keep this instance putting it in another collection.

(have added a little animation, but this is not the point here)

[image]